# Disable auto-mounting in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, mount, automounting, d-bus

I'm working on creating an Ubuntu variant that has a lot of forensic analysis tools etc installed. However I can't seem to find out how to disable auto-mounting at all..I want it to NEVER mount anything, I always want to mount something manually.

I've done some searching and found this: [How can I use gsettings to disable device automount in Ubuntu 16.04?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/282918/how-can-i-use-gsettings-to-disable-device-automount-in-ubuntu-16-04?newreg=ea315c9760954c15895403d56cd2a646)

However, if I use: gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.media-handling automount false

It still auto-mounts. Also the thread says something about

> The reason it failed on this occasion seemed to be caused by the lack
>   of environment variables being set, notably $DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS.

Now I have now idea what this last part mean, anyone care to explain or have any other solution to fully disable auto-mounting cd/usb/sata etc.

Comment: `apt purge udisk\*`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way of doing that is to write an udev rule that makes udisks2 ignore any added block devices. This can be done by dropping a file `10-myudisks2.rules` in `/etc/udev/rules.d` with the rule:

```
ACTION=="add|change", SUBSYSTEM=="block", ENV{UDISKS_IGNORE}="1"
```

This is documented in:

```
man 7 udev
man 8 udisks
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this did work indeed. I selected your comment as the answer. Have a good day!

Answer (score 3):

We also recently has this issue - we wanted only authorized USB Drives to be used. This is how we accomplished it - Using Ubuntu 16.

## Disable the /media folder

Disable non root user access to the media folder

```
chmod 400 /media
```

## Make an Approved Mount Point

Provide an alternative mount point for approved USB Drives.

```
mkdir /approvedusb
mkdir /approvedusb/financepen
chmod -R 777 /approvedusb
```

## Insert Approved USB Drive

We need to calculate the approved USB Drives **blkid**

```
su blkid
```

Then write the UUID Code into the **/etc/fstab**

```
UUID=AEF0-9F26  /approvedusb/financepen  auto,user,rw,defaults,nobootwait      0 0
```

Answer (score 2):

if its fuse mounts there are settings for gnome and mate desktop as such:

```
  gsettings set org.mate.media-handling automount false

  gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.media-handling automount false
```

Its also important to keep in mind that this is a per user setting.
So it is valid only for the current desktop user....

check with:

```
gsettings list-recursively  org.mate.media-handling
```

and

```
gsettings list-recursively  org.gnome.desktop.media-handling
```

Due to the mixed nature of the mate desktop (there are always some gnome apps I use) there seem to be some gnome settings leaking into the desktop configuration.
So I always set both parts to make sure.....

Comment: Doesn't work for hot-plugged SATA drives.